# How to lock/unlock files from performing crud operations using angular?

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

Basically, I have a  with a list of files fetched from blob storage,on which users can perform crud.  I'd like to set the permission to particular files or folders so that other users cannot accidentally delete or modify the files/folder.  How can I achieve it using angular? or azure blob storage? How can we know if files are being used? or user has to manually lock the files so that other users won't be able to modify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to set the permission to particular files or folder so that
> other user cannot accidentally delete or modify the files/folder. How
> can I achieve it using angular? or azure blob storage?

You can certainly lock files in Azure Blob Storage by acquiring lease on a blob. Once the lease is acquired on a blob, the blob can't be deleted or modified as long as the blob is leased unless the request includes lease id. However locking is not the same as setting permissions. You can learn more about blob leasing here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob.

If using File Storage (instead of Blob Storage) is an option, then it provides much better functionality. Essentially what you can do is set attributes on a file or a folder and make then read-only. As long as the file/folder is read-only, no changes can be made to that file. Setting file attributes is accomplished by changing the properties of a file. You can learn more about setting file properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-file-properties (search for `x-ms-file-attributes` on this page).

Comment: this will be from azure storage part, can we also show some message to user from angular application? like "this file is locked and cannot be deleted" or something like that? because users will not have direct access to azure storage.

Comment: `can we also show some message to user from angular application?` - Yes. You can fetch properties of a blob or a file and that will have this information.